# Linear equation integrating factor method

Tags: integrating-factor

I want to ask simple questions.

$$ dy/dx + p(x)y=q(x)$$

In courses, I see always $$p(x)y$$ but what if $$ p(x)y^2$$ or $$p(x)y^3$$ or more ?

It doesn't change anything I guess but I want to ask anyway.

I mean what if

$$ dx/dx + y^3=5x$$
will p(x) = 1 again ?

Comment: The ODE $dy/dx+p(x)y=q(x)$ is linear but $dy/dx+p(x)y^{n>1}=q(x)$ is not linear.

Comment: yes, I don't get it. I am trying to solve one question and it says use the given formula (not this formula but same with these only there is $$e^p(x)dx... $$ . Why they ask this question if I can't solve with these formula?

Comment: My bad, I found the problem. looks like i had to change the equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrating factor method is applicable only to linear differential equations of the form
$$
{dy \over dx} + P(x) y = Q(x) \tag{1}
$$

For solving (1), we define the integrating factor
$$
\mu = \exp\left( \int P(x) dx \right)
$$
and find the general solution of (1) with the formula
$$
y \, \mu = \int \mu Q(x) \, dx + C
$$
where $C$ is an integration constant.

However, if you consider the ODE as
$$
{dy \over dx} + P(x) y^2 = Q(x) \tag{2}
$$
or
$$
{dy \over dx} + P(x) y^3 = Q(x) \tag{3}
$$
then (2) and (3) are nonlinear differential equations due to the presence of $y^2$ or $y^3$ in them. In such cases, you cannot use the integration factor method to solve them.